# Connect Python to Teradata Connection Error

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, teradata

I'm using sqlalchemy trying to connect to Teradata via ODBC as I need to be able to read/write to Teradata.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import sqlalchemy_teradata

user = 'user'
pasw='pasw'
host = 'host'

# connect
td_engine = create_engine("teradata://"+user+":"+pasw+"@"+host+"/?authentication=ODBC?driver=Teradata")

#execute sql
sql = "select * from table"
result = td_engine.execute(sql)
```

However I get the following error.

(teradata.api.DatabaseError) (0, '[28000] [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver] User Specified Mechanism for Logon is Not Available')
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/4xp6)

The link provided is not very informative unless I'm missing something.  The error is from Teradata but I'm not sure what it actually means.  It looks like it saying that I can't use ODBC? Any suggestions or alternatives?

Comment: Looking at https://docs.teradata.com/reader/xM8ikCYjHVqRVRRtAf6b~g/SmNPHCERnMbQXbUPNeDVbw, which seems related, but may not be, I'm not really familiar with TD, it looks like ODBC is not a valid authentication method.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! I actually use the ODBC Administrator to create a connection and call that connection in Excel.  In the link you shared, if you keep scrolling down, you’ll run into the ODBC section eventually.

Comment: It does say ODBC is a valid driver type. It is *not* in the list of valid authentication mechanisms, however. See https://docs.teradata.com/reader/xM8ikCYjHVqRVRRtAf6b~g/cLAiocGbL0x5Ak8oV_1Riw The preferred keyword is Mechanism though Authentication is accepted as an alias. If you can use 64-bit Python 3.4+ consider using the newer *teradatasqlalchemy* package instead of *sqlalchemy_teradata*.